# specify which API is documented by Swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I'm new to swagger and have it installed and running but it's picking up far more API files than desired. I have been hunting a way to specify which API is documented.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can put an ApiExplorerSettings attribute on a controller to remove it from Swagger:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class TestApiController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

If you want to apply this on a lot of controllers based on some logic,
it can be done e.g. with an action model convention: https://github.com/juunas11/AspNetCoreHideRoutesFromSwagger/blob/983bad788755b4a81d2cce30f82bc28887b61924/HideRoutesFromSwagger/Controllers/SecondController.cs#L18-L28

```
public class ActionHidingConvention : IActionModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ActionModel action)
    {
        // Replace with any logic you want
        if (action.Controller.ControllerName == "Second")
        {
            action.ApiExplorer.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The convention is added in ConfigureServices like:

```
services.AddControllers(o =>
{
    o.Conventions.Add(new ActionHidingConvention());
});
```

Comment: This works, i've found it's trying to document every single controller no matter if its an APIController or not and there are a lot of controllers. Is there an inverse way of doing it so instead of marking all 80 controllers with that attribute I can tell swagger to only document the one I want.  None the less what you've posted does solve the problem. Thank you

Comment: There might be some way through settings or controller conventions..

Comment: @user174634 I added an example of doing this with a convention. This might make it a lot easier for you.

Comment: Nice,  I spend too much time looking for existing properties to use and rarely consider trying to implement my own like this. Appreciate the help this works nicely.